# iAd is not displaying ads in my approved game

Tags: ios, iad, workbench

I just finished an update to an iPhone app which included ads. I have signed the contract on iTunes Connect and have integrated the iAd framework with my app. When running the simulator I got test ads running in my app.

However, now that the app is on the app store (it has been about a week since I put ads into it). Whenever I go to the app on my phone there are no ads. Additionally I have around 300 downloads so far.

When I got iAd Workbench and try to view the information on my apps I get something like this:

iAd Network is temporarily unavailable

Sorry: We were unable to locate information relating to your account. Please try again later. If the problem persist please contact us.

Am I missing something? Do I just need to wait for them to review something? I have contacted iAd but have not had a response.

Comment: Do you have iAd contract activated?

Comment: It's in the "Contract in Effect" group with my free apps and paid apps contracts.

Comment: For your information, iAd is working perfect. Check if you have implemented iAd delegate methods also

Comment: I have implemented the delegate methods already. I did that before my app was submitted. I want to know why iAd workbench is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem. So I had been making individual instances of `adViewBanner` in each of my view controllers. I replaced that by making an `adViewBanner` in my `AppDelegate` and then put an instance of that on each of my pages. Once the update was accepted with this change iAd workbench started working and the error message went away.