# How do I test iAd on iOS device? Where will I see the setup iAd network option?

Tags: ios, itunes, iad, banner

I am trying to test iAd on iOS device and some posts from 2013 says that you need to "set-up iAd network" in itunes connect. I dont see any such option in Itunes connect. Does that option exist in itunes connect?

Can anyone suggest what do i need to do to test iAd on iOS? Am i missing something.

Right now when i run my App, all i see is the colorful animation saying "You are connected to iAd network". Does this mean iAd is working already, and when I submit the app real adds will be displayed automatically?

Answer (score 1):

If you are seeing the "You are connected to iAd network" in the iAd banner it means that you have successfully integrated iAd with your application.

If you are not sure, check iTunes Connect to see if you have filled out the iAd contract.

Additionally, if this is for an app that you have released onto the app store yet you still cannot get the ads to work I would suggest looking at this: [iAd is not displaying ads in my approved game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24706078/iad-is-not-displaying-ads-in-my-approved-game).